# Writing SSM ParameterStore update once when many are trying from Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

We've inherited an application that runs on Lambda. On initialization, this App reads a configuration stored on ParameterStore and if a certain value is out of date, then that value is updated and the app can continue.

The problem is that many users (about 7 concurrent at any one time) can run this app, and they could hit the same update nearly at the same time and therefore cause ParameterStore to throw a PutParameter throttle-back error.

To avoid that and to update the ParameterStore  value only once per day rather than on every run, we've devised a simple solution, and we're wanting to get some advice on whether it makes sense or not...

Here are the steps we're thinking:

1. Random sleep between 1 and 10 seconds ("queue" up calls to minimize clashes -- perhaps this isn't necessary??)
2. Does an S3 object exist for today: obj_MMDDYYYY (signals that the PStore update has been done today)
3. If YES then skip updating ParameterStore value
4. If NO then create S3 obj_MMDDYYYY (today's date),  run the Update ParameterStore value

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So, could it be that you're really after consistent reads/writes?  Once the data is written, you want to ensure that any other Lambda 'client' reading this value will get the updated value?  Perhaps Parameter Store is not the right solution in this case? DynamoDB supports strongly consistent reads as a potential alternative and (depending on the anticipated throughput) may not be too expensive.

Comment: I agree with Norman because basic purpose of parameter store is to securly store the confidential data that aren't subjected to be changed frequently

Comment: I agree, but we have what we have until  a full rework, which is not what is being called for now due to constraints.